# How to setup Dagger private dependency within Android specific module using new gradle implementation?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dagger-2, dagger

I'm migrating my project's gradle setup to the new `api` and `implementation` configurations instead of the now [deprecated `compile`](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html). I'm trying to use `implementation` as much as possible but I have hit a roadblock with Dagger.

I have an Android library module where I setup a Dagger module with some private dependencies. One of those is an `RxLocation` singleton:

```
@Singleton
@Provides
RxLocation provideRxLocation(@LocationContext Context context) {
    return new RxLocation(context);
}
```

This dependency is only used within the same dagger module as a dependency to things I actually want to expose. For example:

```
@Singleton
@Provides
Observable<Location> provideLocationUpdates(RxLocation rxLocation, LocationRequest locationRequest) {
    //build observable with RxLocation here
}
```

I don't want the RxLocation to "leak" to other modules so I'm trying to import it with the `implementation` configuration. However, Dagger generates a `LocationModule_ProvideRxLocationFactory` in my app module which obviously imports the `RxLocation` there, breaking the build.

Is there anything I can do about it other than setup the `RxLocation`  instance manually (without dagger annotations) in my module?

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to achieve. Dagger will generate classes, yes, why private? What for? What do you mean by expose? How? Why/How does it break the build? `@Singleton` usually marks the root of your dependencies, so adding things to it seems like a counter-intuitive way if you wanted to "hide" something.

Comment: @DavidMedenjak thanks. 
> why private? Because I don't want to expose that dependency outside of the Dagger module. I just want to use Dagger's convenient way to provide a dependency but _only_ to other dependencies inside that same module. > What do you mean by expose? By expose I mean exposing it outside of the dagger module. In my example above, I can do `@Inject RxLocation rxLocation;` anywhere where I'm injecting with a component that uses that module. How to prevent that? Hope this clarifies a bit.